# bootstrap 3 + angularjs and select hack

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

i have this html code

```
<div class="input-group">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" name="distance" ng-model="calculatorData.distance" placeholder="Distancia"  required>
          <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                <span id="distance_unity_text">Kilometros</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                <input type="hidden" name="distance_unity" ng-model="calculatorData.distance_unity" value="km">
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li> <a data-value="km" href="#">Kilometros</a></li>
                <li> <a data-value="m"  href="#">Metros</a></li>
                <li> <a data-value="mi" href="#">Millas</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div><!-- /input-group-btn -->
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
```

and this jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
   $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
    var $target = $( event.currentTarget ).closest('.input-group-btn');
    var selText = $(this).text();
    var selValue =  $(this).attr('data-value');
    $target.find("input[name=distance_unity]").val(selValue);
    $target.find("#distance_unity_text").text(selText);

    });
});
```

looks here  http://jsfiddle.net/asj8x/

ok, this code works, but now i try to implementing angularjs

i cant bind the value of selected option to the model of angularjs calculatorData.distance_unity

aditionally i try with selects or dropdown but break the style of the group input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a partial solution is get the value directly in the controller

```
.controller('utilityController', function($scope, $http, Utility) {
$scope.calculatorData = {};

$scope.loading = false;

$scope.calculateData = function() {
    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.calculatorData.distance_unity = $("input[name=distance_unity]").val(); //get the hidden value

    Utility.save($scope.calculatorData)
        .success(function(data) {
```